# Get information using python, SPARQL ,DBpedia and Wikidata

Tags: sparql, dbpedia, wikidata, sparqlwrapper

I have a CSV file with a list of names in English and Hebrew, I need to get some information on.

The data I need is
"name-Hebrew name-English DBpedia-URL date birth place birth dateDeath placeDeath  entry_where_found"

for each person, the "entry_where_found" should return if I found the information on DBpedia or wiki data.

I thought of something like this:

```
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/> 
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> 

SELECT ?person WHERE { 
  SERVICE <http://dbpedia.org/sparql> {?person a dbo:Person }
  SERVICE <https://query.wikidata.org/sparql> { ?person wdt:P31 wd:Q5 }
}
```

to query both DBpedia and wikidata, and something like this:

```
SELECT ?instance_of ?label_he ?label_en ?place_of_birthLabel ?date_of_birth ?place_of_death ?place_of_deathLabel ?date_of_death ?URL WHERE {
  ?instance_of rdfs:label ?label_he.
  ?instance_of rdfs:label ?label_en.
  ?instance_of wdt:P31 wd:Q5.
  ?instance_of wdt:P19 ?place_of_birth.
  ?instance_of wdt:P569 ?date_of_birth.
  ?instance_of wdt:P20 ?place_of_death.
  ?instance_of wdt:P570 ?date_of_death.
  OPTIONAL { ?instance_of wdt:P31 ?record_label. }
  OPTIONAL { ?instance_of wdt:P31 ?instance_of. }
  OPTIONAL { ?instance_of wdt:P2699 ?URL. }
  FILTER(((LANG(?label_he)) = "he") && ((LANG(?label_en)) = "en"))
}
```

But I don't know how to add a specific name to find each time, and how to combine the query with the first code.

Can someone help?
Thank You!

Comment: The name has to be assigned as the literal value of the `rdfs:label` property, e.g. `?instance_of rdfs:label "Albert Einstein"@en`. For non-exact matching, `filter(regex(...))` is the standard SPARQL way to go. Indeed you have to put the triple patterns you want to retrieve inside the `SERVICE` clause for each dataset.

Comment: Hi, I tried adding the {  ?instance_of rdfs:label "Albert Einstein"@en} but I get an error. this is my query https://pastebin.com/FYjTu6bd

Comment: Nevermind I got it working with this query: https://pastebin.com/m6zkbUct now how can I use python to send a different name each time?

Comment: Do you understand why you got an error? The trailing `.` is missing to denote the end of a triple pattern which is necessary at least if more triple patterns follow.

Comment: "how can I use python" -> I don't see the difficulty here - just replace the appropriate position of the SPARQL query string by the name.

Comment: Hi, one last thing, I split my query one for wikidata and one for DBpedia, but my query doesn't work for DBpedia, does it need to have a different syntax? I also tried running it online at  http://dbpedia.org/sparql.

Comment: Well, each dataset usually has different schema entities in addition to the common vocabularies like RDF/RDFS/OWL/XSD, thus, different URIs will be used for domain knowledge. Wikidata is **not** DBpedia,